# Symfony2 WebTestCase ignores my database changes when run via ant in Jenkins

Tags: testing, symfony, jenkins, propel

I have a system that catches login events and triggers a response (popping up a modal) after the redirect based on values stored in a database.

In order to properly test this I have set up a functional test that clears this database table and populates it with a set of test data.

When I run the test individually it works fine. However when I run it in Jenkins (or just using ant as Jenkins does) it does not.

Investigation shows that when the WebTestCase logs in it is acting as if the changes I made to the database have not been made. I have tried clearing the instancePools in various places but it makes no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post the code for the test and your ant file.

Comment: The relevant bit of the build.xml file is:
    <target name="phpunit" description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">  
      <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="${basedir}/bin/phpunit" failonerror="true">  
        <arg line="-c app" />  
      </exec>  
    </target>

Comment: Not sure what is going on with the markdown here, cant seem to format the code. Will post up the test soon, need to foobar-ify it before I post it up and am too busy right now

Comment: The test code is going to be more helpful in this case.